# Definition of (co)homology of groups and Lie algebras: actions and augmentations

Tags: ring-theory, lie-algebras, homological-algebra

In the [Chevalley-Eilenberg chain complex](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chevalley-Eilenberg+chain+complex), what is $ux_i$? What does "trivial $\frak{g}$-module $k$" mean? Below I denote $R=k$ (any commutative unital ring).

How is the augmentation (last map in the resolution) $U(\mathfrak{g})\to R$ defined? As $u\!=\!\sum_w\!r\!_ww \mapsto r_1$ or $u\!=\!\sum_w\!r\!_ww \mapsto \sum_w\!r\!_w$? Is $R$ an $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module via this augmentation? Here $w=x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_k}$ is a word in $U(\mathfrak{g})=T(\mathfrak{g})/\langle a\otimes b-b\otimes a-[a,b]\rangle=R\langle x_i|x_ix_j-x_jx_i-[x_i,x_j]\rangle$.

In group (co)homology's bar resolution, the augmentation (last map in the resolution) $R[G]\to R$ sends $\sum_g\!r\!_gg \mapsto \sum_g\!r\!_g$ and $R$ is an $R[G]$-module via this map, i.e. $(\sum_g\!r_gg)r=\sum_g\!r_gr$, correct?

I'm using Weibel 6.5.1 and 7.7.1. The statements are not explicit enough.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you thinking that $U(\frak{g}) $ acts on $ \frak{g} $? From the definition of $ d$ , $ u x_i \in U(\frak{g}) $, so it is the opposite $ \frak{g} $ acts on $ U(\frak{g}) $, by adjoint action.

I don't understand your notation $ u\!=\!\sum_w\!r\!_ww $. What are the $ w $ here?

I am not sure about this but, I think the proper map $ U(\frak{g}) \rightarrow $ $k$ is just the projection of the ground field inside $ U(\frak{g}) $. I think this is the only way to get $ d^2 = 0 $.

EDIT: The lie algebra acts on itself by adjoint action, $ g.h = [g,h] $. This extends to a derivation on the tensor algebra, and $ U(\frak{g}) $.

Recall that the universal enveloping algebra has a filtration coming from the grading of the tensor algebra. The zeroth vector space in this filtration is just the ground field.

Comment: What is "adjoint action"? What is "projection of the ground field"? Please be more explicit.

Comment: I hope my post will point you towards the right direction, but if you want the precise details, you should look in the textbooks. The lie algebra acts on itself by adjoint action, $ g.h = [g,h] $. This extends to a derivation on the tensor algebra, and $ U(\frak{g}) $.

Comment: Are you suggesting $u\!=\!\sum_w\!r\!_ww \mapsto r_1$ or $u\!=\!\sum_w\!r\!_ww \mapsto \sum_w\!r\!_w$? Are you sure of the right choice?

Comment: I am suggesting the first, but I am not entirely sure. It doesn't seem to me the second case will let $ d^2 = 0 $.

Comment: If you will look at example 7.3.5 in weibel, it looks like the augmentation map $ \epsilon $ indeed sends $ g \rightarrow 0 $.

Comment: I don't understand 7.3.5: it says it is analogous to the augmentation $R[G]\to G$ for groups, but 6.1.5 seems to contradict that.

Comment: It is analogous in the sense they are both augmentation maps. Beyond this, I am not sure :(